# QSqlRelationalTableModel::removerow() deletes the row from table but not from the model

Tags: sql, qt

The code speaks better:

```
model = new QSqlRelationalTableModel();
model->setEditStrategy(QSqlRelationalTableModel::OnRowChange);
model->setTable("members");
model->setRelation(Member_TeamID, QSqlRelation("teams", "ID", "Name"));
model->setSort(Member_Name, Qt::AscendingOrder);
model->select();

mapper = new QDataWidgetMapper();
mapper->setSubmitPolicy(QDataWidgetMapper::ManualSubmit);
mapper->setModel(model);
mapper->setItemDelegate(new QSqlRelationalDelegate());

void member_detail::deleteMember()

{
    int row = mapper->currentIndex();
    bool x=    model->removeRow(row);
    mapper->submit();
    mapper->setCurrentIndex(qMin(row, model->rowCount() - 1)); 
    QMessageBox::critical(0,"W",QString::number(x)); // This Echos false 

}
```

Simply When I call deleteMember , The record is not removed from the model but it's removed from the database (I Check against it using Navicat)
Specs: Qt 5.0.2 Linux 64-bit , g++ as compiler

Answer (score 0):

From `QSqlTableModel::removeRows` docs:

> Emits the beforeDelete() signal before a row is deleted. When the edit
>   strategy is OnManualSubmit signal emission is delayed until
>   submitAll() is called.

So check the edit strategy you're using and try to call `model->submitAll()` after changes.

Comment: My Edit Strategy is OnRowChange , but I found the solution in the docs 
For OnFieldChange and OnRowChange, only one row may be deleted at a time and only if no other row has a cached change. Deletions are submitted immediately to the database. The model retains a blank row for successfully deleted row until refreshed with select().

I will try it .